# Axiom of Universality implies sets of arbitrary cardinality with each element the value of the graph $(A,R,p)$

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

Exercise $3.7$ in Section $3$, Chapter $14$ of Hrbacek and Jech's "Introduction to Set Theory" ($3^{\text{rd}}$ edition):

> Let $(A,R,p)$ be an extensional pointed graph, $W$ its well-founded part, and $p \notin W$. Assuming the Axiom of Universality, show that there are sets of arbitrarily large cardinality, all elements of which are values of this graph. [*Hint*: Take the union of an arbitrary collection of disjoint copies of $(A,R)$; identify their well-founded parts, show that the resulting structure is extensional, and consider its injective decoration.]

The graph $(A^{\prime}, R^{\prime})$, where $A^{\prime} = \bigcup_{i \in S}A_{i}$, $R^{\prime} = \bigcup_{i \in S}R_{i}$, each $(A_{i}, R_{i})$ a copy of $(A,R)$ with $A_{i} \cap A_{j} = \emptyset$, $R_{i} \cap R_{j} = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$, is extensional, I think, though I don't know how to show this (I suspect this has to do with $p_{i} \notin W_{i}, p_{j} \notin W_{j}$; I'd like some help with this). Presumably the injective decoration $f$ will mean that each $f(p_{i})$ is the value of the graph $(A,R,p)$ (why?), and that $B = \{ f(p_{i}) \mid i \in S \}$ is of cardinality $\vert S \vert$ ($S$ an arbitrary set), as $p_{i} \neq p_{j}$ implies $f(p_{i}) \neq f(p_{j})$ for $i \neq j$. I am not sure, however, why the hint asks the reader to identify the well-founded parts of each $(A_{i}, R_{i})$, and I would like some clarification with regard to this (and for any errors in my reasoning to be pointed out as well).

Relevant definitions:

> $\bf{1.11}$ **Definition** $R$ is *extensional* on A if $x \neq y$ implies $\text{ext}_{R}(x) \neq \text{ext}_{R}(y)$ for all $x,y \in A$.

> $\bf{3.13}$ **Axiom of Universality** *Every extensional graph has an injective decoration.*

$W_{\lambda}$ is the *well-founded part* of $(A,R)$ if $W_{\lambda} = W_{\lambda + 1}$, where $W_{\alpha}$ is defined as follows: $$ \begin{align} W_{0} &= \emptyset \\ 
W_{\alpha + 1} &= \{ a \in A \mid \text{ext}_{R}(a) \subseteq W_{\alpha} \} \\ 
W_{\alpha} &= \bigcup_{\beta \lt \alpha} W_{\beta} \text{ for limit } \alpha \neq 0 \end{align}$$

Other possibly relevant definitions can be found here: [Two graphs are bisimulation equivalent iff their decorations have the same value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661815/two-graphs-are-bisimulation-equivalent-iff-their-decorations-have-the-same-value).